# iPad 2 UIImageview display image incorrectly (incorrect render)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimageview

I've created a new simple iOS project in xcode 9.2 and set iOS Deployment target to iOS 8.0 then add UIImageview to a view and set image name to the UIImageview , start and run on iPad 2 (iOS 8.1.3) see the result in image below ,the imageview render incorrectly

[image: Click here to see the Result]

[image: Click here to see original image]

Comment: set content Model to aspect Fit

Comment: I've tried that but it not work

Comment: already there a bug reported to apple. Its a known issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/93743

> Issue is included in release notes for Xcode 9.2, hopeffully will be fixed soon https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW936
>   When using Xcode 9.2 to create apps that deploy to iOS 8 and later, images in the asset catalog may be corrupted when viewed on devices running iOS 8.3 and earlier. (35379713)  Workaround: Build the app using Xcode 9.1, or use Xcode 9.2 and set the deployment target to iOS 8.4 or later.